# Error during compass build with an old ruby project

Tags: ruby, sass, compass

I've been using compass from http://compass-style.org/ to manage my sites css for a long time.
I have to make a small intervention on this website but the compass build command doesn't work anymore.

I'm trying to lauch the build command like this : `bundle exec compass watch -e production --force --sourcemap`

Here the error :

```
bundler: failed to load command: compass (/home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass)
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/set/sorted_set.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>': The `SortedSet` class has been extracted from the `set` library.You must use the `sorted_set` gem or other alternatives. (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/set/sorted_set.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:13:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:13:in `<module:ChunkyPNG>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png.rb:150:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png.rb:150:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:4:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:474:in `exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:128:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/set/sorted_set.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- sorted_set (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/set/sorted_set.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:13:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:13:in `<module:ChunkyPNG>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png/palette.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png.rb:150:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/chunky_png-1.3.4/lib/chunky_png.rb:150:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:4:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:474:in `exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:128:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- oily_png (LoadError)
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines/chunky_png_engine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites/engines.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions/sprites.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `each'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `require'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /home/hedy/Sites/myproject.fr/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/compass:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:474:in `exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:128:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.23/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

My gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "sass", "~> 3.4.19"
gem "compass", "~> 1.0.3"
gem "susy", "~> 2.2.6"
gem "breakpoint", "~> 2.5.0"
gem "sugarcss", "~> 1.0.0"
```

How can I get this build command work again ?

Comment: The error message says `SortedSet` was extracted from the set library that `compass` depends on. Try doing `gem install sorted_set` to install the gem that contains the class